# How to implement parameterized AND condition in Codeigniter using Query Helper Methods

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a LEFT join query with an AND condition:

```
SELECT a.s_id AS sid,a.s_prog_id AS progid,a.s_acssn_id AS ssnid,a.s_name AS sname,a.s_admission_no AS sadmsnno,a.s_photo_name AS sphotonm,
       b.sa_atten_code AS acode 
FROM student_mst a 
LEFT JOIN stu_attendance b 
ON a.s_id = b.sa_s_id AND b.sa_atten_dt = ?
```

In the Codeigniter, I'm trying to implement the above query like:-

```
$this->db->select($this->select_column);
$this->db->from('student_mst a');
$this->db->join('stu_attendance b', 'a.s_id = b.sa_stu_id', 'left');
```

Now, what should I write for the AND condition with parameter? How to implement AND condition in Codeigniter? Please help.

In the query above, b.sa_atten_dt = ? is suppose to receive a date like '2021-08-21' from a post variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the "AND" condition in the standard "ON" declaration.

In your case:
`$this->db->join('stu_attendance b', 'a.s_id = b.sa_stu_id AND b.sa_atten_dt = ?', 'left');`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Andrea. and how do I pass the parameter value of (?) ....code example would be very good.

Comment: @gomeshmunda well it depends on what you have to filter your results on. I mean, b.sa_atten_dt what is referring to? If it's a fixed known value you can simply write it in the query.

Comment: When I use a.s_id = b.sa_stu_id AND b.sa_atten_dt = ? then it shows me SQL syntax error like '?' is not recognized :(

Comment: You have to provide the value you want to filter your result on. Assuming b.sa_atten_dt is a place you can write b.sa_atten_dt='Harvard'. Edit your question with some data representation so we can help you further.

Comment: If the value is received from a user you can concatenate the value to the query with the function `$this->db->escape(INSERT_VALUE_HERE)`. Or use the queries binding to use an array of values. You can find more info on escaping and bindings of database queries in the docs https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#escaping-queries